# update tor of Whonix Gateway

Tags: whonix

I'm using Whonix Gateway and Workstation. 
Recently Arm shows

***Tor 0.2.9.9(unrecommended)***

(unrecommended is red)

How can I update to a newer version of tor?
Is it dangerous to use as it is ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should follow the steps outlined on the [Whonix Security Guide](https://www.whonix.org/wiki/Security_Guide#Updates).

In simple terms, you should only need to run the following commands:

1. `apt-get update`
2. `apt-get dist-upgrade`
3. `reboot`

By the looks of it, [0.2.9.9](https://deb.whonix.org/dists/jessie/main/binary-amd64/Packages) is the latest version distributed for Whonix.

```
Package: tor
Version: 0.2.9.9-1~d80.jessie+1
```

There have been some bugfixes since then, most prominently CVE-2017-0376 which only affects onion services. The consensus suggests that it's [not a recommended client version currently](https://consensus-health.torproject.org/#recommendedversions) but I don't think it's explicitly known to be unsafe if you're only using it as a client.

Comment: Thank you for replying.
But I've already done it,because whonix-check asked me to do so.
But nothing happened as for version of tor.I tried one more time,but the result was the same.

Comment: I've added some more details.